# Java swing "children" windows

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

Sorry for really simple question, but I wasnt able to find anything in the net, probably because I dont know the right terms to look for.

When you have a desktop application, there are many so called children windows: one for options, one for "about" and so on. How to make them in Java Swing (with NetBeans tools -  optional)?

So far I just created another JFrame and on relevant event opened it the same way Main function launches, well, main JFrame. But there's something wrong with this method: when I close child window via x in the upper right corner, whole program terminates as if I was closing the main window. This is probably because NetBeans auto generated code for x and I can find and change it somewhere... but still I have a feeling that there must be a simpler proper way to add children JFrames (or JPanels or whatever is it for children windows) ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ... But there's something wrong with this
>   method: when I close child window via
>   x in the upper right corner, whole
>   program terminates as if I was closing
>   the main window. ...

Well, I would say you are on the right path. Just make sure that you do the following for your child frames :

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then closing the child windows won't shut down your entire application.

HTH ! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean a Dialog Window (see [How to Make Dialogs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)) that you likely want to be *modal* to block user input to all other windows in the program (see [An Overview of Dialogs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#overview))?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean something like Options window. I.e. Firefox Preferences window. Unless it is called dialog window too.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the frame-design mode -> select your frame -> in the properties, the fist option. Select `Dispose on close`.

If you don't see the props: `Ctrl + Shift + 7` or `Window (in the frame menu) -> Properties`

Answer (score 1):

If you create frames, they aren't considered children windows. You can not set an owner for them as you could a JDialog. If you did want to create another JFrame, then you would have to set the close operation

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

instead of

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The EXIT_ON_CLOSE operation will call 
    System.exit(0); 
which will terminate the JVM. Just remember, that if your main JFrame is set to 
    DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE 
then you must make sure that all your other frames have been properly disposed of, otherwise it won't exit until they have been.

Comment: Thank you all of you ;) Too bad I cannot formally accept more than one answer, all of them were helpful :)